# How can I export the Kanban board in TFS 2015?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We have started migrating our kanban board to TFS 2015, although we also need the ability to export it perhaps to a PDF which can then be emailed / printed out as / when needed.

Although we cannot find a way to do this seemingly simple task.

thanks

Comment: This site is for programming questions. You show some code, we (maybe) try help fix it. We are not general software tech support.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to export the Kanban board to pdf on the Web Portal. If you want to share this to your custom or other team's mate. You can set appropriate permissions to their user account to make sure they can only view the items needed.